# close android app with down botton

Tags: android, forceclose

I have a problem with the back button event and a code to close my app. I explain:

I have an app with two activities. The first activity displays a list of events in a listview. When you click on one of these events a new activity that can confirm attendance at the selected event opens. If this second activity you press the button that confirms attendance returns to the main activity.

My problem is that if once you hold an event from the main activity and confirm second activity giving the button that returns you to the main activity when the main activity to give back button instead of closing the app returns to the second activity.

Therefore I want to record the event of pressing the button back and close the app, I tested with:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

and too:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            exit(0);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

thank you very much for your time and help

**ANSWER**

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
            homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Why?  Is there an "exit" button on this web page?  There is no need in normal apps to use `exit()`.  Please do not try to change the behaviour of the home or back keys.  It is anti-Android and is not how users expect apps to behave.

Comment: this code works!!  `Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
         homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
         homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(homeIntent);`

Comment: Good.  I'm pleased that you fixed it.  Please add your code as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set up the activities wrong. You should set a result in the second activity, and then call it's finish() method. Then the back button will always work as expected and you won't have to do weird hacks like that.

Comment: thanks but i have wrote the code that is  in SOLUTION in the first activity and it works well